# Python/ Numpy How to use arctan or arctan2 on the interval 0, pi/2?

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry

Is it possible use the arctan or arctan2 numpy functions with the result always on the 1st quadrant (0,pi/2)?
Thanks

Comment: If you use the absolute value you obtain a 1st quadrant value i.e.: np.arctan( abs(x) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to calculate the minimum "deviation" angle (in the interval `[0,pi/2]`) between the `x`-axis and the segment connecting points (0, 0) and (x, y), you could use:

```
phi = numpy.arctan2(y, x)
phi = min(abs(phi), math.pi - abs(phi))
```

or:

```
phi = numpy.arctan2(abs(y), abs(x))
```